# Windows 8.1 Keeps Turning Off Automatic Updates

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

My OS keeps turning off automatic Windows updates without even logging off or restarting the computer.

Action center icon in the task bar warns me about choosing an option for Windows update as if I haven't chosen countless times already.

It started to get really annoying to keep choosing a Windows update option 5 - 10 times a day.

I really appreciate any help you can provide on this matter.

Things I have tried so far;

- I have tried [How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058) suggested by [Tetsujin](https://superuser.com/users/347380/tetsujin). Unfortunately didn't help my case
- Tried following commands; `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update" /v AUOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`
   and then `sc config wuauserv start= auto` as suggested [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/1445914/windows-7-automatic-update-keeps-turning-itself-off-requesting-to-be-turned-on-over-and-over#post_21533820).
- Googling. Tried few suggestions which didn't help my case.

Comment: If it came with Windows 8.1 then you still need to install `Update 1` which is also known as the "Spring Update" this particular update is required for ALL updates release after it.  So have you installed this update yet?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, my OS is up to date. It just asks me what is my preference about Windows updates every now and then as if I haven't chosen an update settings yet.

Comment: Till today I had this problem. I decided to use Ubuntu from now on so I'm not looking for a solution any longer. Thank you **Ramhound** and **Tetsujin** for your time.

Answer (score 3):

See [How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058)

The page may pop up a generic 'Fix General Problems' in front of that page. If so, run that first, then this one. I've known it take 2 attempts before it works.

Comment: thanks! I guess that did the trick. It said it found some problems and it fixed it. Unfortunately I can't up-vote your answer yet due to lack of rep. points I have.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have one machine it doesn't fix & another it did - the main difference, the fixed one has had a repair install done with a full Win 7.1 Both machines were originally 7.0 & had all updates since. idk what is the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a laptop you are having the issue with? If so, it may be turning off automatic updates when your battery drops below a certain percentage (I believe it is around 15 or 20 percent). I have Windows 8.1 on my Toshiba Satellite laptop and automatic update turns off when it goes into power saver mode.

Comment: thank you for your reply. This sounds very logical. Yes, it was my laptop. Unfortunately I was experiencing this issue when I had about 70 - 80 % battery. However your answer might help someone.

Sorry I can't up-vote your comment due to my low rep.
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS a little while after posting my question. I must say, I never looked back.